# Passar dados PHP para um text area

Tags: php, html5, formulário, session, textarea

- > Olá. Sou iniciante em PHP e preciso Completar o seguinte desafio.
  >
  > Problema (3)
  >
  > É um produto computacional para recepção de informações acadêmicas.
  >
  > Ações:
  >
  > 1. Fazer um formulário (prob02_form_disciplinas.php) que receba o nome
  >    de um aluno, o nome de uma disciplina e a nota dessa disciplina.
  > 2. Realizar um cadastro, em que envia-se os dados para o próprio
  >    formulário (prob02_form_disciplinas.php), que retornará o campo nome
  >    preenchido e um componente textarea para listar as disciplinas
  >    cadastradas a cada vez que o formulário for enviado. O formulário deve
  >    manter o valor anterior do textarea e acrescentar os dados da nova
  >    disciplina enviada (no textarea deverá ser adicionado uma linha para
  >    cada disciplina no formato: Disciplina: nomedisciplina - média:
  >    valormédia).

O meu código que estou desenvolvendo é o seguinte

```
<php? session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Problema 02</title>
</head>
<style>
...............................................
</style>
<body>
    <h1>Problema 2</h1>
    <h2>Produto computacional para recepção de informações acadêmicas.</h2>

    <form action="prob02_form_disciplinas.php" method="get" >

        <label for="aluno"><p>Aluno:</p>
            <input type="text" name="aluno" class="entrada" placeholder="Insira Seu Nome Aqui ">
        </label><br><br>


        <label for="disciplina"><p>Disciplina:</p>
            <input type="text" name="disciplina" class="entrada2" placeholder="Informe Aqui a Disciplina">
        </label><br><br> 


        <label for="nota"><p>Nota:</p>
            <input type="number" name="nota"  class="entrada3" placeholder="Informe aqui a sua nota">
           <input type="submit" id="button" value="➪ ➪ Cadastrar ➪ ➪">
        </label>
    </form>      

  
<?php 

if ( isset($_GET["aluno"]) && isset($_GET["disciplina"]) && isset($_GET["nota"]))
 {

    // $aluno =  $_GET["aluno"];
    // $disciplina = $_GET["id"];
    // $nota = $_GET["nota"];

    $_SESSION['lista_dados'] [] = $_GET['aluno'];
    $_SESSION['lista_dados'] [] = $_GET['disciplina'];
    $_SESSION['lista_dados'] [] = $_GET['nota'];

    if (isset($_SESSION['lista_dados'])) 
    {
         $lista_dados = $_SESSION['lista_dados'];
    }

 }

 
?>
   <textarea name="textarrea" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
     <p>teste</p>
   </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

O código mesmo está incompleto. Pois me deu um branco e não sei como pegar os dados do processamento. Salvar com session e fazer aparecer dentro do text area.

Answer (score -4):

Você pode usar o seguinte código para passar dados PHP para uma área de texto:

```php
<?php

$data = "Hello World!";

?>

<textarea><?php echo $data; ?></textarea>
```

Além disso, se você deseja passar dados de um envio de formulário para uma área de texto, pode usar o seguinte código:

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<textarea><?php echo $data; ?></textarea>
```

Lembre-se de usar as funções de escape adequadas ao enviar dados para uma área de texto para evitar vulnerabilidades XSS.